# Get Sum of Values where the Date is before or at set Date but each id only counts once

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to get the Sum of a Value (Amount) where the Date is Before or at a set Date.
This could be solved with a simple `SUMIFS(Amount range, Date range, "<=" & Date)`

Now my problem is that the Table I get my Data from contains some IDs multiple time for example ID 2 could exists x times. But for my Sum I only want ID 2 to be counted once but it should still be the closest before the set Date.

[image]

Here you can see my current status as an example but as you can see the first date does not consider all values he should because the Date of ID 2 and ID 4 are lower than the `MAXIFS` return but still need to be added to the sum.

I also know it could be solved with VBA but would preferer a formula solution.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combo of `SUMIFS` and `MAXIFS` to achieve this. Starting inside the formula, the MAXIFS will locate the most recent date <= to your target date (which is in cell I1 below). Then your SUMIFS will use that as part of it's criteria.

Cell F2 formula:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,E2,C:C,MAXIFS(C:C,A:A,E2,C:C,"<="&$I$1))
```

Results:

[image]